# Complexity of absolute difference and sum

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

How can I solve the following questions in complexity:

1. *|O(f(n)) – O(f(n))| = ?* (Complexity of absolute value of *O(f(n)) – O(f(n))*).
2. *O(f(n))+  O(f(n)) = ?*

Answer (score 0):

1. *|O(f(n)) – O(f(n))| = O(f(n))*. That is basically the only thing you can say about it. This is because you're subtracting, from a function growing at most like *f(n)*, another function growing at most like *f(n)*. The result (pre the absolute value) can be even negative (e.g., when subtracting *2 f(n) = O(f(n))*, but it is clearly not larger than a function growing like *f(n)*.
2. *O(f(n)) + O(f(n)) = O(f(n))*. This is easy to prove throught the basic definition of *O*.

Comment: I see. But, what if both functions are exactly the same? Is there a chance |O(f(n)) – O(f(n))| will be equal to zero? or can I say that there is no chance (because of other factors) both of them will run with the same complexity ?

Comment: @RanYagil That's just a special case. *0 = O(f(n))*.